# Pagination with collection.fetch() in backbone.marionette

Tags: backbone.js, marionette

I am trying to implement pagination with backbone.marionette's 
compositeView by first doing an initial fetch:

```
collection.fetch({reset: true})
```

To load additional models into the same collection,

```
collection.fetch({reset: false, remove: false})
```

is used.

I saw that on each use of fetch() with {reset: false}
muliple add events are triggered (for every model added.)
Thats fine basically, but when looking into the annotated source
of the compositeView's appendHtml function in marionette the follwing 
statement is given:

> buffering happens on reset events and initial renders in order to
>   reduce the number of inserts into the document, which are expensive.

While this is great for the initial fetch (only 1 browser reflow), every
subsequent fetch with {reset: false} could get pretty expensive 
(reflow on every single model thats added). It really seems to
append() the itemView every single time - causing a reflow 
(compositeView.isBuffering is false).

Is there any way to "batch" process the models and do a single insert 
(same as done on the reset event)?

Does this need an overwrite in the appendHtml implementation 
and implement the batch logic by myself?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(I assume you don't want to use Backbone.paginator, for some reason. If that isn't the case, use the plugin ;-D).

You could use a technique similar to the filtered collection used here: https://github.com/davidsulc/marionette-gentle-introduction/blob/master/assets/js/entities/common.js#L2 (instanciation at https://github.com/davidsulc/marionette-gentle-introduction/blob/master/assets/js/apps/contacts/list/list_controller.js#L13).

Basically: you provide a "paginated collection" to the view, and what the paginated collection does is:

- initially, return a "cloned" copy of the original collection
- when you fetch on the original collection, add the fetched events in "batch" to the cloned collection, which will trigger the view to refresh (because it's listening to the cloned collection, not the original)

To minimize reflows, you can try the following:

- silence the events that the collection listens to ("add", etc.)
- when a group of models gets added, create a **new** instance of a collection view with only the new models
- render the new collection view (but don't show it anywhere), and manually append the `newView.el` to the right place in the DOM
- destroy the `newView`

Unfortunately, once you need to start optimizing, you tend to need to handle a bunch of things by hand...

Comment: Well thank you. As my type of pagination is similar to the infinitiv paging of backbone.paginator i looked into the provided example. While it definitly helps to implement the mechanism itself, it adds the item views one by one causing an expensive reflow for each. So it does not directly reference the problem I have written about. Implementing an effective way of updating the UI is left to the actual imlementation...

Comment: the filtrered collection mentioned seems to be very well thought out for the purpose it tries to solve but a bit too complex for what I want to achieve. I basically look for a efficient UI update after fetching the initial collection data with as little browser reflows as possible.

Comment: Thanks again for the update. I will evaluate the suggested method and try to implement something like that. Because of the given input, I will mark the question as accepted - optimization does not come for free.